# How do I get the ghost writers?

Tags: yooka-laylee

The ghost writers seem to all have a puzzle related to them. It seems there's only the yellow one that stays there to be taken, all the others you need to do something before you can pick them up.

So what types of ghost writers are there and how do I pick them up?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

**Yellow**: This guy is the easiest of the Ghost Writers to catch in Yooka-Laylee. It doesn’t move at all, so simply find it and walk through it to catch him.

**Red**: One of the tougher Ghost Writers, this one attacks the duo. As a result, you’ll need to evade its attacks and deal some damage right back at it straight away. As you deal damage, it’ll change color, indicating you’re close to catching it. Don’t let up and it’ll soon be yours.

**Green**: There’s no real trick to catching this Ghost Writer. It’ll run away from you, so just chase after it and try and cut off its escape routes.

**Blue**: You’ll hear this one giggling away when you’re nearby, and it’ll occasionally reveal itself before disappearing again. You’ll need to unlock Laylee’s Sonar Shot ability and press Y/ Triangle to fire it in its general direction. You’ll then be able to collect it.

**Pink**: You’ll find this one with its mouth agape, and that’s your clue with what you have to do before you can grab it. Simply feed it something by using Yooka’s Slurp State ability until it becomes a more solid color. Run into it to round off your collection of Ghost Writers.

Unfortunately, there’s no recurring location you’ll find each of the Ghost Writers, but you’ll often stumble upon them as you explore each Grand Tome in Yooka-Laylee. Having trouble finding a particular one? Let us know down in the comments below and we’ll do our best to help you out.

Credit for this answer goes to [this website](http://twinfinite.net/2017/04/yooka-laylee-ghost-writers-how-get-what-they-are/).